# Extending User.IsInRole(string role)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, extension-methods

I need to extend the `User.IsInRole(string role)` to account for a `WebApplicationId`.  I have created the following extension method:

```
public static class RoleHelper
{
    public static bool IsUserInRole(this User user, string role, int webApplicationId)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

`this User user` references this class:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<long, Login, UserRole, Claim>
{
    public User() : base()
    {
        PreviousPasswords = new List<PreviousPassword>();
    }

    ......
}
```

In my view when I call `User.IsInRole("Administrator", 2)` I receive the error `No overload method 'IsInRole' takes 2 arguments`  I added a reference in the Web.Config file in the View folder to where the extension method is stored, so I know that part is working.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your error message talks about "IsInRole", but your implementation is called "IsUserInRole" - is that the problem?

Comment: Wow, I knew it had to be something simple.  I fixed that and I had to change the first parameter to `this IPrincipal user`.  Thank you!